# std::vector size in header

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have small question about std::vector. In main.h i try to make fixed size int vector

```
std::vector<int> foo(7);
```

But g++ gived this error:

```
../test/main.h:21:26: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
 std::vector<int> foo(7);
../main/main.h:21:26: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

How can i create private vector variable of fixed size length? Or should i simply make in constructor

```
for(int i=0; i<7;i++){
    foo.push_back(0);
}
```

Comment: If you want a fixed-size vector, use std::array or even a naked C array.

Comment: In " main.h" ? That's probably the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `foo` is a data member, your syntax is invalid. In general, you can initialize a data member of type T like this:

```
T foo{ctor_args};
```

or this

```
T foo = T(ctor_args);
```

However, `std::vector<int>` has a constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list<int>`, which means that the first form would yield a size-1 vector with a single element of value 7. So you are stuck with the second form:

```
std::vector<int> foo = std::vector<int>(7);
```

If you are stuck with a pre-C++11 compiler, you would need to use a constructor:

```
class bar
{
public:
    bar() : foo(7) {}
private:
  std::vector<int> foo;
};
```

and take care to initialize the vector in all constructors (if applicable.)

Comment: Thanks. This has helped me. I'm using second variant.

Comment: @juanchopanza doesn't the first variant use the initializer list constructor?

Comment: @UNIm95 You did well to so that, because the first one is syntactically correct, but semantically "wrong" in this particular case. See my edit.

Comment: Oh. Thanks.  I had much luck to use proper statement.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to initialize a class member (other than built-in type), is to use the initialisation list.

So the best solution here, is to construct your vector of length 7 in the initilization list of your class constructor:

(I also recommend you to use a define for your fixed value 7. If you change it to 8 in the futur your will not have to change the value 7 on all your code)

file.h:

```
#define YOURCLASSFOOSIZE 7
class yourClass
{
public:
    yourClass(): foo(YOURCLASSFOOSIZE) {}
private:
    std::vector<int> foo;
};
```

file.cpp :

```
for(int i=0; i < YOURCLASSFOOSIZE; i++)
{
    foo.push_back(0);
}
```