# How to initialize a vector to a certain length in a class?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a simple class with a member that is a vector.  I want to initialize that vector to have a specific size in the class, but I get an error.  Here is my code:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
std::vector<int> m_ray_fbos(5);
}
```

This gives me the warning (in Visual Studio 2017) `expected a typed identifier`

I have also tried `std::vector<int> m_ray_fbos(5, 0);`

The only think I can get to work is `std::vector<int> m_ray_fbos = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };` but obviously this is not ideal for long vectors.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a way to specify the size of a vector in a class definition?

Comment: I don't think you should and/or can initialize a vector when defining it. And, setting a vector size in a header file is bad practice.Why not doing it in your class constructor, as follow : m_ray_fbos.reserve(5)?

Comment: You can have a look at this question to understand why it is not working : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298026/stdvector-size-in-header

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `()` parentheses style of initializer is not permitted by the syntax for a member within a class definition.  (I'm not really certain why.)  The only valid forms of initializer for members within the class definition are the `{}` braced initializer-list or an initializer that starts with `=`.

And that gets in your way here, since:

```
std::vector<int> m_ray_fbos{5};
```

or

```
std::vector<int> m_ray_fbos = {5};
```

call the wrong `vector` constructor and don't give the results you want.  And

```
std::vector<int> m_ray_fbos = 5;
```

won't work because the constructor you need is `explicit`, and the `=` symbol makes that copy initialization, so `explicit` constructors are not considered.

The simplest answer is probably

```
std::vector<int> m_ray_fbos = std::vector<int>(5);
```

You could maybe also do something like

```
std::vector<int> m_ray_fbos = vec_of_size(5);
```

if you had enough other reasons to write or use a `vec_of_size` class function or free function.

Answer (score 4):

You can initialise your vector via member initialisation list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class MyClass
{
    std::vector<int> m_ray_fbos;
public:

    MyClass() : m_ray_fbos(5) {}
    size_t GetSize() const
    {
        return m_ray_fbos.size();
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass c;
    std::cout << c.GetSize() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/QTOs7l

`5`