# Why can't i initialize vector of certain length in a class obviously?

Tags: c++, class, vector, initialization

I'm trying to initialize a vector with a preferred size, but visual studio gives an error C2059.

```
class Solution {
private:
    vector<int> firsttosee(26);
};
```

I've read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144685/how-to-initialize-a-vector-to-a-certain-length-in-a-class), yet in the answer the author mentions:

> The () parentheses style of initializer is not permitted by the syntax for a member within a class definition. (I'm not really certain why.)

Please, help understanding, why the obvious vector initialization doesn't work in a class

Comment: @user4581301 He can not use such an initialization for class members. He needs to use brace or equal initialization as for example vector<int> myvec{26};

Comment: The use of `()` is just reserved for declaring member functions. `vector<int> myvec();` is a function returning a vector. For data members you can use `{value}` or `= value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error C2059 is a syntax error.

As the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50144862/65863) clearly says, standard C++ syntax simply does not allow you to use `()` to directly initialize a class member from inside the class declaration, hence your error.

You can, however, use `()` to initialize the member in the [constructor's member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), eg:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    vector<int> myvec;

    MyClass() : myvec(26) {}
};
```

Or, since C++11, you can use `{}` in the class member declaration <sup>1</sup>, eg:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    vector<int> myvec{26};
};
```

<sup>1</sup>: which is actually a bit problematic for `std::vector` in particular, as it will actually invoke the `std::initializer_list` constructor instead of the `size_t` constructor, thus leaving you with a `vector` holding 1 element with a value of 26, instead of holding 26 elements with a value of 0.

Otherwise, you can create a separate object using `()` and then initialize the class member with it, eg:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    vector<int> myvec = vector<int>(26);
};
```

Comment: So you mean it's simply a rule in the compiler that doesn't allow? No explanations why it's not allowed? Just seems weird to me, sorry for curiosity.

Comment: @nuchyobitva It's the rule of the language. Initialization rules have gone many changes over the years. I'm sure we've not seen the last of the changes yet :-)

Comment: _"have gone many changes"_ - Insert a _through_ there and it'll probably make more sense. Time for bed :-)